# jQuery, AJAX wont show container in DIV

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have this jQuery script in my web page:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    function callAjax(){
        $('#lastlogins').load("ur.php");
    }
    setInterval(callAjax, 1000 );
});
</script>
```

But, in container lastlogins, there isn't shown file ur.php, it is just empty. I have created div like that:

```
<div id="lastlogins">
</div>
```

Comment: Do you see any error on the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any wrong on your code. Only problem would be with your `ur.php` file. Just try to access your file directly and see, if that works.

In the meanwhile, refer my sample code.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    function callAjax(){
        $('#lastlogins').load("/SivaCharan/EGxWL/show");
    }
    setInterval(callAjax, 1000 );
});
</script>
<div id="lastlogins">
</div>
```

Refer my **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/kHaW6/2/)**

Comment: Yes, it was the problem in my ur.php file. Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

After a quick review of the `.load` function, there can only be one possibility... your PHP file is not returning anything useful. Run it directly in a browser and make sure it returns valid HTML.

Your jQuery function is correct as is.